# Inline p tags inside div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display 3 inline `p` tags inside a `div` container but I have problem when I change the `font-size` of one `p` tag. Do I need to adjust the `line-height` of `p` tag or is there a universal command?

Also, is there any way except using `margin-left` or `margin-right` to put a space between `p` tags?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1sccy6t/1/)

```
.container{
width:200px;
padding:10px;
display:inline;
}

.one{
float:left;
font-size:25px;
}

.two{
float:left;
}

.three{
float:left;
}


<div class="container">
 <p class="one">
  sentence one
 </p>
 <p class="two">
  sentence two
 </p>
 <p class="three">
  sentence three
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you need all the content in the same line? In that case, the 200px width will wrap your text.

Comment: "have problem"? WHAT problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `float` to set inline elements. Use `display:inline;`

```
.one{
  font-size:25px;
}
.container p {
  display:inline;
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/t1sccy6t/3/).

**BUT** I suggest you to avoid [`p`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) for inline elements, use [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) instead that are build for that.

> The HTML `<span>` element is a generic inline container for phrasing content

Workind [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/vwhLjkfy/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block` , if you want to use `p` tag

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8ru9o02/)

but as **paolo.basso99** said , to display `inline` elements, you should use `span` tag.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario can be achieved using **CSS Flexbox**. To make them equally spaced and vertically centered you need to apply these CSS properties.

Have a look at the code at **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1sccy6t/4/)**.

Just add the following properties to parent element in your case its `.container`

```
.container {  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```